# Displaying ALL audit logs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was wondering if someone could help me out, I'm trying to display ALL of the audit logs into a channel using discord.js in the simplest way possible.
So far I've managed to display most events (having a hard time with adding roles logs and removing roles logs), but anything that can help display all of the audit logs would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question well.

Do you want to display all audit logs? If yes, you can find more information [**here**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogs?scrollTo=entries).

Then you can use the `.entries` property. This will give you access to the following: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=action

With this you can request whatever you want from the audit logs.